# Ajax Doc Cart for virtuemart not working

Tags: module, joomla2.5

mod_ajax_dock cart Not working in which come following error.

this.load undefined or can not Cannot read property 'style'.

so plz help me solve this question

Answer (score 0):

That's generally a Javascript conflict caused by the various scripts that your site is loading. The first place to start is to install jQuery Easy to strip out multiple instances of jQuery as well as the usually loaded Mootools. You will have to mess around with the settings, I usually have it strip everything out and see what breaks, then start adding scripts back in until everything works.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327